# How To Convert Type? An explicit conversion exists Error

Tags: asp.net

How do I correct this Anonymous Type Conversion error?

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<object>'
```

**Happens on Line**

```
select new { ITEMID = p.PRESSRELEASEID };
```

**the Code**

```
ddlYear.DataSource = years;
                    ddlYear.DataBind();
                    ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Year", ""));

                    IQueryable<object> pressreleases;
                    DateTime startdate, enddate;

                    if (this.iFilterMonth != null && this.iFilterMonth > 0 && this.iFilterYear != null)
                    {
                        startdate = new DateTime((int)this.iFilterYear, (int)this.iFilterMonth, 1);
                        enddate = startdate.AddMonths(1);

                        pressreleases = from p in db.tblPressReleases
                                        where p.prdate.Date >= startdate.Date && p.prdate.Date < enddate.Date
                                        orderby p.prdate descending
                                        select new { ITEMID = p.PRESSRELEASEID };
                    }
```

from the suggested comments seems like I AM running 3.5 in web.config? if That is indeed the cause of my error how to change the version?

```
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.Services, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Comment: What version of .Net?

Comment: @SLaks I went from 4.0 To 4.5 Dev version DID NOT cause any issue but The live version did

Comment: This error should not happen on 4.0 or later.  Make sure you aren't actually on 3.5.

Comment: @SLaks So this will be a web.config issue then?